# How to create own authTokenType in Android?

Tags: android, authentication, auth-token

I want to create an authentication token to my account. I create own account type, and add my account to the device
I create an app, that make accounts whit my account type. I create another app, that create authentication token to the devices accounts.

```
getAuthToken(account, "mail", false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

But this method i create token to a google account. What shuold i write instead of "mail", to create token to my ow account type?